# Pytorch Geometric Expected all tensors to be on the same device [demo code not working]

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-geometric

I wanted to try out the link prediction functionality [demonstrated here](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/link_pred.py). Here are my versions:

```
PyTorch Geometric v2.0.2
PyTorch v1.9.0+cu111
```

I'm very baffled why `cuda:0` is printed for every tensor yet I see the error when I pass the data through `RandomLinkSplit`.

```
import torch

import torch_geometric.transforms as T
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
from torch_geometric.utils import negative_sampling

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
transform = T.Compose([
    T.NormalizeFeatures(),
    T.ToDevice(device),
])

dataset = Planetoid(root='/tmp/Planetoid', name='Cora', transform=transform)

data = dataset[0]
print(data.to_dict())
print(data.keys)

transform = T.RandomLinkSplit(num_val=0.05, num_test=0.1, is_undirected=True,)
train_data, val_data, test_data = transform(data)
```

output:

```
{'x': tensor([[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0'), 'edge_index': tensor([[   0,    0,    0,  ..., 2707, 2707, 2707],
        [ 633, 1862, 2582,  ...,  598, 1473, 2706]], device='cuda:0'), 'y': tensor([3, 4, 4,  ..., 3, 3, 3], device='cuda:0'), 'train_mask': tensor([ True,  True,  True,  ..., False, False, False], device='cuda:0'), 'val_mask': tensor([False, False, False,  ..., False, False, False], device='cuda:0'), 'test_mask': tensor([False, False, False,  ...,  True,  True,  True], device='cuda:0')}
['val_mask', 'test_mask', 'edge_index', 'train_mask', 'x', 'y']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_72/414574324.py in <module>
     20 
     21 transform = T.RandomLinkSplit(num_val=0.05, num_test=0.1, is_undirected=True,)
---> 22 train_data, val_data, test_data = transform(data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch_geometric/transforms/random_link_split.py in __call__(self, data)
    204                 train_edges,
    205                 neg_edge_index[:, num_neg_val + num_neg_test:],
--> 206                 out=train_store,
    207             )
    208             self._create_label(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch_geometric/transforms/random_link_split.py in _create_label(self, store, index, neg_edge_index, out)
    284             if neg_edge_index.numel() > 0:
    285                 edge_label = torch.cat([edge_label, neg_edge_label], dim=0)
--> 286                 edge_index = torch.cat([edge_index, neg_edge_index], dim=-1)
    287             out[self.key] = edge_label
    288             out[f'{self.key}_index'] = edge_index

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking arugment for argument tensors in method wrapper__cat)
```

Comment: I think you might be onto something. Care to open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: ah yep, I found the culprit and have opened an issue on Github https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/3641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed a [bug](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/3641). Thank you for reporting it.